one header and N payloads in xml file
I have a xml file with n headers and n payloads
<header1>
  payload1 
</header1>
<header1>
  payload2
</header1>

How can I remove headers and let only the first one using python or Linux commands? The output will be
 <header1>
  payload1 
  payload2
</header1>


It would be helpful if you posted an example of the output you are trying to generate from that example input (and if the example were well-formed, valid XML).

It would be great if you could share the file
Here's one of my suggestions on how you can do it
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# Find all headers by their tag name
headers = root.findall('.//header1') # Use './/' to find all occurrences

for header in headers[1:]:
    root.remove(header)

I'm not sure of my proposed solution, so please correct me if you need to.
Thanks

Is sample.xml is:
<header1>
  payload1 
</header1>
<header1>
  payload2
</header1>

Then you can do:
import xml.etree.ElementTree

tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring("<tmp>" + open("sample.xml", "r").read() + "</tmp>")
print(*[h.text.strip() for h in tree.findall(".//header1")], sep="\n")

Prints:
payload1
payload2


Or with single command (using python3):
python -c 'import xml.etree.ElementTree as E;print(*[h.text.strip() for h in E.fromstring("<tmp>" + open("sample.xml", "r").read() + "</tmp>").findall(".//header1")], sep="\n")'


I assume your xml is valid and have one root element:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_= """
<root>
<header1>
  payload1 
</header1>
<header1>
  payload2
</header1>
</root>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_)
  
new = ET.Element("root")
header1= ET.SubElement(new, "header1")
header1.text ='\n    '+ '\n    '.join([payl.text.strip() for payl in root.findall("header1")])+'\n  '

tree = ET.ElementTree(new)
ET.indent(tree, space='  ')
tree.write("test.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")
ET.dump(tree)

Output file:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
  <header1>
    payload1
    payload2
  </header1>
</root>

